# Difficulty compiling with Javac - Issues

Tags: java, compilation

I have the following directory structure
c:\jibx\tutorial\example23\
The example 23 contains the following files

[image]

Now I am trying to compile CustomerManager java file only which references other classes in this folder.The code for CustomerManager java file is straightforward

```
package example23;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.jibx.runtime.*;

public class CustomerManager 
{

                 public CustomerManager()
                 {
            try 
            {
            IBindingFactory bfact = BindingDirectory.getFactory(Customer.class);
            IUnmarshallingContext uctx = bfact.createUnmarshallingContext();

            Object obj = uctx.unmarshalDocument(new FileInputStream("C:/jibx/tutorial/example23/customer.xml"), null);
            Customer customer = (Customer)obj;
            System.out.print(customer.street+", "+customer.city);
            IMarshallingContext mctx = bfact.createMarshallingContext();
            mctx.setIndent(4);
            mctx.marshalDocument(obj, "UTF-8", null, new FileOutputStream("C:/jibx/tutorial/example23/customer2.xml"));
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (JiBXException e) 
            { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
                  }   //end method

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
 new CustomerManager();
 }

 }//end class
```

Now this file contains references to files in its top directory such as c:\jibx\lib (the file itself is in c:\jibx\tutorial\example23)

I tried the following to reference those libraries and to compile the file

```
C:\jibx\tutorial>javac  -classpath c:\jibx\lib\  example23\CustomerManager.java

and the output i got was
example23\CustomerManager.java:7: error: package org.jibx.runtime does not exist

import org.jibx.runtime.*;
^
example23\CustomerManager.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                               IBindingFactory bfact = BindingDirectory.getFactory(Customer.class);
                                ^
symbol:   class IBindingFactory
location: class CustomerManager
example23\CustomerManager.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                            IBindingFactory bfact = BindingDirectory.getFactory(Customer.class);

   ^
symbol:   class Customer
location: class CustomerManager
example23\CustomerManager.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                              IBindingFactory bfact = BindingDirectory.getFact
ory(Customer.class);
                                                    ^
 symbol:   variable BindingDirectory
 location: class CustomerManager
 example23\CustomerManager.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                            IUnmarshallingContext uctx = bfact.createUnmarsh
allingContext();
                            ^
symbol:   class IUnmarshallingContext
location: class CustomerManager
example23\CustomerManager.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
                            Customer customer = (Customer)obj;
                            ^
symbol:   class Customer
location: class CustomerManager
example23\CustomerManager.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
                            Customer customer = (Customer)obj;
                                                 ^
symbol:   class Customer
location: class CustomerManager
example23\CustomerManager.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                            IMarshallingContext mctx = bfact.createMarshalli
ngContext();
                            ^
symbol:   class IMarshallingContext
location: class CustomerManager
example23\CustomerManager.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
                            catch (JiBXException e)
                                   ^
symbol:   class JiBXException
location: class CustomerManager
9 errors

C:\jibx\tutorial>
```

Any suggestions on how i cld solve this problem ?

Comment: Yesterday also you had the same problem and this forum advised you to correct your classpath . Can you please try having a look at PATH / CLASSPATH before your proceed any further ?

Comment: Yes I did have a look at them thats why i started another post. I was going to reply to those posts however the AddComment section doesnt really help

Answer (score 5):

Your problem lies in the following line I think

```
-classpath c:\jibx\lib\
```

Does this directory contain jar files?

in that case you could try using a glob like so:

```
-classpath c:\jibx\lib\*.jar
```

This way you will include all the jar files in the c:\jibx\lib\ directory in your classpath.

Comment: Yes the lib files are in the first one and i tried using *.jar style too but that doesnt work either

Comment: here is the output that i am getting [link](http://i1076.photobucket.com/albums/w459/rajeshkhan808/output.png)

Comment: I managed to reduce the errors. Now it only needs the path to the class files that are being used which i have already provided by using "cp ." the image output is at [link](http://i1076.photobucket.com/albums/w459/rajeshkhan808/output-1.png) I would appreciate any suggestions u might have

Comment: Could you post that Customer.java file?
Also try running it using powershell, normally the best way to do this would be using an ANT build file which does support globs (*?.). But powershell should be fine for testing

Answer (score 3):

You have to add .jar file in your [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

for instance,

```
javac  -cp .;c:\jibx\lib\your_lib.jar  example23\CustomerManager.java
```

Comment: is -cp an abbreviation of -classpath ? can we use -cp instead ??

Comment: Yes! Take a look at the link I've posted.

Comment: So here is what I got - Command Used:     C:\jibx\tutorial\example23>javac  -cp .;c:\jibx\lib\org.eclipse.core.runtime.jar
  CustomerManager.java       Part of Output:
CustomerManager.java:7: error: package org.jibx.runtime does not exist import org.jibx.runtime.*; 
                       ^            Is it possible that javac has a problem resolving imports with * in them ??

Comment: here is the output that i am getting [link](http://i1076.photobucket.com/albums/w459/rajeshkhan808/output.png)

Comment: I managed to reduce the errors. Now it only needs the path to the class files that are being used which i have already provided by using "cp ." the image output is at [link](http://i1076.photobucket.com/albums/w459/rajeshkhan808/output-1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by:

```
C:\jibx\tutorial>javac  -cp .\example23\*;.;.;c:\jibx\lib\jibx-run.jar;  .\example23\CustomerManager.java
```

Thanks for your great suggestions